# Are there any flaws in this pseudocode?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis

I'm developing an algorithm that cracks small RSA keys (And theoretically bigg ones too, though might take some time), and was wondering if anyone you spot any flaws in this python code:

```
N = public_key.n
E = public_key.e

X = floor(sqrt(N))
Y = ~(-1 << N)

P = X

if P % 2 == 0:
    P = P + 1

loop = True

while P < N and loop is True:
    if N % P == 0:
        loop = False
        break
    P += 2

Q = N / P
T = (P-1) * (Q-1) // gcd(P-1, Q-1)

D = mod_inverse(E, T)
```

To show that this works:

```
N = public_key.n = 1867460849
E = public_key.e = 65537

X = floor(sqrt(N)) = 43214

P = X = 43214

if P % 2 == 0:
    P = P + 1

loop = True

while P < N and loop is True:
    if N % P == 0:
        loop = False
        (P = 55667)
        break
    P += 2

Q = N / P = 33547
T = (P-1) * (Q-1) // gcd(P-1, Q-1) = 933685818

D = mod_inverse(E, T) = 594429209
```

Can anybody find any mathematical or cryptographic flaws in the code?

EDIT:

I'm not looking for code review, just a review of the alorithm from a *cryptographic* point of view.

EDIT 2:

A beta version of this code is now availiable at https://github.com/Legorooj/RSAKeyHackerGUI. (June 2019)

Comment: If you are seeking for a code review of these snippets (including performance optimisations), you should ask on [codereview.se] as questions about code are generally off-topic here. I'm not closing this is as it explicitly asks about this variant of trial division.

Comment: I also plan to upload this to github at some point. AKA when it works with no errors whatsoever.

Comment: How many trial divisions do you do, if you try all values between $\sqrt{n}$ and $n$? How many, if you in contrast try all values less than $\sqrt{n}$? Your algorithm scales with $n$, when trial division should scale with $\sqrt{n}$. So basically, it is much, much worse than the most basic and straight-forward algorithm. If you want to start your iteration at the square root, then iterate towards zero.

Comment: @tylo if it is a normal RSA key, at least one of the prime factors will be above `sqrt(n) `.

Comment: On a broader note: I would call it a flaw (since you stated it like that in the title), that you ignored the entire scientific advances in integer factorization over the last  ~50 years. This might only be interesting to people, who don't know anything about integer factorization yet.

Comment: Yes, but also there is one below. I was not arguing correctness. I was arguing runtime.  To make it more obvious, here is an example with $n \approx 10000$: what is faster, doing 50 steps between 100 and 0 or 4450 steps from 100 to 10000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard trial-division algorithm which for some reason starts at $\sqrt{N}$ instead of at $2$ with the trial-divisors. Yes, it is functionally correct and will always find a non-trivial factor for composite numbers.

However, if $N$ has more than two prime factors, this will only find composite factors if the prime factors are balanced. This is as for all prime factors $p_i\approx\sqrt[3]N<\sqrt N$ and so the algorithm will at best find pairs of factors. Also note that for multi-prime RSA which uses 3 or more balanced prime factors the post-processing will yield an invalid value, because the computation of $\varphi(N)$ is different. If you want an example for that try $N=11\cdot 13\cdot 17$.

Also for the keys for which this is functionally correct, this is very slow for realistically sized cryptographic RSA moduli. In particular to factor a standard 2048-bit RSA modulus, this will take about $2^{1024}$ loop iterations and even if every single one of them runs in [the smallest yet practically physically used amount of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time) and if you would parallelize this so that every atom in the universe runs it in parallel it would still take $2^{642}$ times the age of the universe to successfully factor. Of course for "small" inputs, that is up to 80 or so bits it should complete in a reasonable amount of time, assuming this is executed reasonably efficiently (i.e. not by an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) without a [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)).

Comment: Thanks! This program is designed to attack standard RSA keys, so It wouldn't work for a multi-prime key.